# CoreData - Getting a NSManagedObject's relationship subset

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Noob question incoming (very simple but not finding the answer anywhere):

I have an entity

```
MY_ENT *my_ent = {initialized elsewhere};
```

This entity has a to-many relationship called `my_rel`

```
NSLog(@"Relations: %lu", my_ent.my_rel.count);
```

> Relations: 15

**I'd like to get a subset of it**, where the field `my_field` equals to @"xx"

I tried to loop on the relations populating a NSArray but no luck (pointers seem deallocated).

```
NSMutableArray *my_rels;
for (MY_REL *my_rel in my_ent.my_rel) {
    if ([my_rel.my_field isEqualToString:@"xx"]) {
        [my_rels addObject:my_rel];
    }
}
```

Maybe I should use a predicate but I don't understand how to use one here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's easier with a predicate. You can do this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"my_field = %@", x];
NSSet *subset = [my_ent.my_rels filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
```